# Is there something i am doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/sales.css'; // Import the CSS file

function Sales() {
  const [propertyData, setPropertyData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data from your Django API using Axios
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/core/for-sale/')
      .then((response) => {
        // Limit the photos to a maximum of four
        const limitedData = response.data.slice(0, 4);
        setPropertyData(limitedData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="sales-container">
      {propertyData.map((property) => (
        <div key={property.id} className="property-card">
          <Link to={`/property/${property.id}`}>
            <img src={property.main_photo} alt={property.title} className="property-image" />
            <h2 className="property-title">{property.title}</h2>
          </Link>
          <p className="property-description">{property.description}</p>
          <p className="property-details">
            {property.bedrooms} Bedrooms | ${property.price}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sales;
```

I was trying to fetch data from a django-rest api. I have installed the axios library, defined the  CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS also added the corsheaders but the images cannot be rendered. I get the following error "Error fetching data: TypeError: response.data.slice is not a function"

Comment: It seems like response.data is not an array, and that's why you are getting this error. I think you're receiving an object, not an array. Confirm this by check response in network tab.

Comment: Slice is used on Arrays. So the response you are getting is not an array. If the response has additional information along with the data , do like this        
  ```const response =await axios.get("url");  const data= response.data;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using DRF viewsets the data will be returned like this:

```
{
 'next': xxxx,
 'previous': xxx,
 'results': [xxxx,xxx]
 'count': xx,
}
```

If that's the case you'd have to do `response.data.results.slice(0,4)`. Otherwise take a look at what the API actually returns and try working with that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the response.data is coming in as null/undefined, how does a sample response look like? Can you post the result when you call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/core/for-sale/` via Postman or the browsable API?

Comment: the response i get from insomnia  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V53HD_SM74-iOIdyGKBOS9fENHqx4P910z0G_HGeNXs/edit?usp=sharing